# Which control should I use for 2D drawing with WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, graphics, drawing

I want to programatically draw a few simple 2D shapes in a WPF application. Which control should I use for that? I've heard that `Canvas` can do that but that it's mostly designed to be a container for other controls and not a "drawing" canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those other controls could be shapes like rectangles, lines, etc., so Canvas may be a good start. If you want to render directly through a function, you could basically use any (user)control as base class, though.

Answer (score 0):

Canvas is meant for drawing, obviously. What is your concern ? if it is Speed, you should have a look on Windows XNA.
Maybe Direct X, Open GL or any library providing access to them could be of some use. Give more details on your needs for an answer.